# Apple rejected my app for crashing on iphone 5

Tags: ios

I know this question has been asked several times, but Im looking for a more general answer.
I have developed an app for iOS 6, I tested it on simulator(Retina 3.5 and 4 inch) and also on an iPhone 4 device.
It has never crashed but when I submitted the app to Apple and they answered with:

> We found that your app crashed upon launch on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.3,

Looking at the crash log[image]

We see that it crashes in line 164 from a index out of bounds, which makes sense because I have this code there:[image]

I added that "if" to stop the execution whenever the `indexTimesArray` was bigger than the length of the array and see why that happened, but I was unable to reproduce the error. I never get an `index out of bounds` as they do...
It's true that I haven't test it on a iPhone 5 device, but I have XCode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 on my computer, and also a iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3, but it's also true that the guys at Apple are getting the app crashed, so how to reproduce the error?
I tried to install the app from [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) because it installs it as a brand new app, just like they do when they test it, but still no errors...

How can I reproduce the error? Could it be a problem with th build settings?

Thanks

[EDIT]
I initialize the contents of timesArray in the init method of the object, like this:

> ```
> - (id)init{    
> self = [super init];    
> df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
> rangeDates = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2013-04-11 10:00", @"2013-04-12 10:00", @"2013-04-13 10:00", @"2013-04-14 10:00", nil];    
> timesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10:00", @"11:00", @"12:00", @"13:00", @"14:00", @"15:00", @"16:00", @"17:00", @"18:00", @"19:00", @"20:00", @"21:00", @"22:00", nil]];    
> colorDictio = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.74 green:0.66 blue:0.37 alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:0.64 green:0.15 blue:0.11 alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:0.313 green:0.65 blue:0.69 alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:0.79 green:0.4 blue:0.59 alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:0.45 green:0.55 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:0.14 green:0.27 blue:0.66 alpha:1.0], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"showers area", @"zinctalks", @"zincnetwork", @"zincshows", @"zinclabs", @"zinczone", nil] ];
> return self;
> }
> ```

Comment: I had faced a similar error earlier with arrays in Objective-C... My suggestion would be to use self with NSMutableArrays or NSArrays.

Comment: you mean declaring the array as an attribute?

Comment: Declare your array with property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* timesArray;`

Comment: then in `.m` file, wherever you use the array use it as `self. timesArray`

Comment: cool, I tried that, but still I wont know if it fizes it until Apple approves it or rejects it.

Comment: You could try downloading older simulators like iOS 6, iOS 5.1 and so on and then test on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mayur, his comment is the right answer, "I had faced a similar error earlier with arrays in Objective-C... My suggestion would be to use self with NSMutableArrays or NSArrays"

Answer (score 1):

To figure out how to reproduce that error you have to look at the code where you create timesArray.

The out of bounds error happens because `[timesArray count]` is less than 2 (or the whole array is nil). So you have to figure out which condition leads to an array with one or zero objects. Maybe it happens because there is no internet connection.

It's always a good idea to wrap objectAtIndex: in a check for the actual size of the array.

I would replace `else {` with `else if ([timesArray count] >= 2) {` and add an additional else that handles <2 arrays.

Comment: why you say the error comes from being the length less than 2? I think it's an out of bounds, in any case I never get that error, what I need is to be able to reproduce the environment where Apple says the app crashes

Comment: Because that's the only way the snippet can throw an out of bounds error. (Besides multi threading race conditions.) The "then" part of the if condition only executes when the bounds allow it. The exception can't happen in there. And in the "else" part the exception does not happen when `count - 2` is 0 or greater. So the only possibility that can cause an exception is an array with less than 2 objects.

Comment: Another question is if you actually get an out of bounds exception. Maybe your code tries to access invalid memory because you made a memory management mistake

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not a OS related error. Your app is crashing because the wrong index of array is being accessed.

1. How can I reproduce the error? : Try to use the same credential which you must have provided to apple.
2. Could it be a problem with th build settings? : No.

To debug the error what you can do is try to print the value of indexTimesArray before the if. Also, try to print all the values you are passing to access the array element. Which will help you track the wrong index which is being sent.

Comment: What do you mean by credential? Also keep in mind that with the tools I have I never get an index out of bounds, what I need is to reproduce the environment of Apple or why it crashes with them and not with me.